# Recommendation for contra-variant and contra-variant vectors in the context of special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, tensor-calculus, covariance

I have just started studying covariant and contra-variant vectors in special relativity. I am finding difficulty understanding this topic. Can anyone recommend a book (with a detailed chapter) or lecture series for the same?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this post on the same topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91593/understanding-the-difference-between-co-and-contra-variant-vectors?rq=1).

Comment: Very illuminating explanations of these matters can be found in "A Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors" by  Daniel Fleisch